# requiring template files with classes

Tags: php, class, function, templates, require

Hi I'm trying to make my own simple template system kind of thing
and I'm just learning about classes so I'm trying to do it with classes and objects.

it works if i put this in top of every document:

```
$template = new Includes('name', 'path');
$include = new Includes('name', 'path');
```

but it feels like it shouldn't be necessary, and its not that pretty.

This is how my code is arranged right now **:**

**index.php:**

```
<?php
require_once 'class_include.php';
$template->loadTemplate('body');
```

**body.php:**

```
 <?php require_once 'class_include.php'; ?>
    <head>

    <?php $template->loadTemplate('head'); ?>

</head>
<body>

<?php
    $template->loadTemplate('sidepanel');
    $template->loadTemplate('content');
?>
</body>
```

**class_include.php:**

```
class Includes {

public function loadTemplate($name, $path = 'template'){
    require_once "$path/$name.php";
}
public function loadInc($name, $path = 'inc'){
    require_once '$path/$name' . '.php';
}
}
$template = new Includes('name', 'path');
$include = new Includes('name', 'path');
```

error message:

***( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function loadTemplate() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\project\template\body.php***

***( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: template in C:\wamp\www\project\template\body.php***

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think that in your code, you should use static methods instead of objects.

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'class_include.php';
Includes::loadTemplate('body');
```

**body.php**

```
<head>
    <?php Includes::loadTemplate('head'); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        Includes::loadTemplate('sidepanel');
        Includes::loadTemplate('content');
    ?>
</body>
```

**class_includes.php**

```
class Includes {

    public static function loadTemplate($name, $path = 'template'){
        require_once "$path/$name.php";
    }

    public static function loadInc($name, $path = 'inc'){
        require_once '$path/$name' . '.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked well, but what is a static method and what are the differences?

Comment: A Static method (or property) allows you to use a class without creating any instance of this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Static_methods

Comment: why would you ever want to use not static ?

Comment: There's some times where you need to use $this in your classes. Static methods have the detail that you don't create instances of classes, so $this is not possible.